# rails - Suggestion on coming up with a secure UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a unique ID to protect something that is very secure.

Right now in Rails I'm doing:

```
uuid = (UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.gsub('-','') + UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.gsub('-',''))
```

What are your thoughts on this method? Smart? Bad? Suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what does secure mean? the probability of a collision?

Comment: `to protect something that is very secure??` o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your identifiers to be unpredictable by any adversary, you will want to use a cryptographically strong pseudo-random number generator. In terms of bit size, 128 bites (or 16 bytes) is a good number.

```
# if using Ruby < 1.9:
require 'active_support/secure_random'

id = SecureRandom.random_bytes(16)
```

There are also the methods `.hex`, `.base64`, and `.urlsafe_base64` for your convenience. These simply generate the corresponding number of random bytes, and then encode the random bytes in the appropriate scheme. For example, `SecureRandom.hex(16)` will give you 32 securely random hex characters.

Comment: I need it URL and EMAIL address wildcard safe,

Answer (score 2):

UUIDs are not designed for strength of security, and shouldn't be a critical part of any security technique.  See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt -- especially section 6.

Comment: Thanks DMW. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to prescribe a solution without more context around your question, but decent quality pseudorandom numbers are likely to be useful.  In Rails, ActiveSupport::SecureRandom is handy for this.

Comment: Very nice, how do you use ActiveSupport::SecureRandom? can you provide an example? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It will generate a v4 random UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) is pure unique across a large namespace for universal unique number to generate a ID in a database.

```
require 'securerandom'
UUID = SecureRandom.uuid
```